# Returning an exit code from C# PowerShell cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am writing a PowerShell cmdlet in C# and this cmdlet is called by a parent process that I have no control over. The parent process has mechanisms in place to handle persistent reboots from the cmdlet if the exit code of the process is 3010. The problem here is that I cannot figure out how to provide a value for the exit code given that the entry point into the cmdlet is:

```
protected override void ProcessRecord() { ... }
```

I have read that cmdlets do not generate an exit code when researching the `$LASTEXITCODE` PS variable. I'm fairly new to PowerShell in general so I am not sure if I am going about this the right way. Does anyone have a way that I can accomplish what I have described?

The cmdlet gets loaded and called by a PS script something like

```
Import-Module "C:\testing\test.dll"
Run-MyCmdlet
```

Comment: Could you show code, how exact your cmdlet is called?

Comment: Made edit now that I have more than my phone to work with.

Comment: What parent process does to call this script? Is it `powershell -File Script.ps1` or something else?

Comment: I don't have a window into how the parent process calls the run script unfortunately, but I would imagine that is the case.

Comment: You can try this: `this.Host.SetShouldExit(3010)` (assuming that your cmdlet inherit from `PSCmdlet`).

Comment: I have tried this and was unable to get a successful exit code.  I also tried inheriting from both PSCmdLet and Cmdlet but they both appear the same result.

Comment: I have a workaround solution for this via returning an object containing an ExitCode property to the call script for the cmdlet, however, I still would like to determine whether or not it is actually possible  to return an integer exit code from a cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

Are looking for a way to determine if the module loaded or for your cmdlet to indicate it failed?

To determine if the module loaded or failed look at the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.2#erroractionpreference)

If you want your cmdlet to report a terminating error look at `Cmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord)` method. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.throwterminatingerror?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0)